# RelativePanel inside a RelativePanel not working as expected UWP C#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, panel, windows-10-universal

I have a UWP App. In the MainPage, I have a the Big RelativePanel that contains a FlipView and a second RelativePanel below it. I want the second RelativePanel (that is Blue and contains the PlayButton and "Listen Now") to have a height relative to the size of the Screen (any Screen) that reaches the AppBar. In the Picture, the size of the screen is 1024x768. In other words I want the blue RelativePanel to cover all the Screen till the AppBar.

```
<RelativePanel x:Name="BigRelativePanel">

    <Image x:Name="LogoImage" Source="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Height="120" Margin="0,20,0,0" RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"/>

    <FlipView x:Name="MenuFlipView" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="350" Margin="0,10,0,0" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.Below="LogoImage">
        <FlipViewItem>
            <GridView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="FirstSixGrids" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{x:Bind myMenu_1}" ItemClick="FirstSixGrids_ItemClick" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuTemplate}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource MenuItemsPanel}"></GridView>
        </FlipViewItem>
    </FlipView>

    <RelativePanel Background="{StaticResource TransparentBlue}"
                   RelativePanel.Below="MenuFlipView"
                   RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">
        <Image x:Name="rotateImage" Source="/Assets/Icons/AnimatedPlay.png" Width="85" Height="85" Margin="0,17,0,0" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" />
        <Button x:Name="PlayButton" Style="{StaticResource CircleButton}" Width="80" Height="80" Margin="0,20,0,0" Foreground="White" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" Click="PlayButton_Click">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Icons/IconPlay.png"/>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock x:Name="radioTimerBlock" Text="Listen Now" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.Below="PlayButton" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
    </RelativePanel>
</RelativePanel>
```

[image]

Comment: What do the `1*` and `625` measures apply to? It looks like this is inside a `<Grid>`

Comment: exactly! a `Grid` with two `RowDefinitions`. Either remove them, or remove the whole `Grid` or set `Grid.RowSpan="2"` to your outer `RelativePanel` and you get what you want.